# how to use threads with file reading/writing?

Tags: java, multithreading, ioexception

A homework assignment asks me to implement a program that counts the words in one or more files (filenames are specified as arguments on the command line) by starting a new thread for each file.

Here's my issue: the run() method can't throw an IOException, because the run() method in the Runnable interface doesn't throw one. I've gotten around the compiler's warnings by putting the File and Scanner constructor calls in the constructor of my class that implements Runnable, but even though it compiles fine now, I still feel shady somehow, like I am doing something not kosher. Any thoughts?

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;

public class WordCounter implements Runnable {
    File inFile;
    Scanner in;
    int characters;
    int words;
    int lines;
    int[] counted;

    public WordCounter(String aFile) throws FileNotFoundException {
        inFile = new File(aFile);
        in = new Scanner(inFile);
        counted = new int[3];
    }

    public int[] getTotals() {
        return counted;
    }

    public void run() {
        characters = 0;
        words = 0;
        lines = 0;
        while (in.hasNextLine()) {

            String thisLine = in.nextLine();
            lines++;
            Scanner line = new Scanner(thisLine);
            while (line.hasNext()) {
                String thisWord = line.next();
                words++;
                characters++; // because each call to line.next() strips a whitespace character
                Scanner word = new Scanner(thisWord);
                word.useDelimiter("");
                while (word.hasNext()) {
                    char ch = word.next().charAt(0);
                    characters++;
                }
            }
        }
        counted[0] = characters;
        counted[1] = words;
        counted[2] = lines;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think a general rule of thumb would be to handle the exception as close to where it is thrown as possible. What is stopping your runnable from handling the exception instead of your main() or whatever is creating the runnables?

I agree that variable initialization is typically best done in the constructor, but when using runnables, you are going to get better performance if that construction takes place in your run() method. I am specifically talking about variables that actually take some time to process; the int[3] isnt going to make a difference whether its in your constructor or run method, but the Scanner and File might depending on what they do upon initialization (e.g., does Scanner buffer the first line of the file for example?).

Comment: I'd thought about doing that, but in the chapter before this one, students were encouraged to *not* catch exceptions in classes, where you might not be able to handle them as effectively as you (or some other programmer) could handle them in the main method that's using your class. (Hope that made sense...) I guess I am still a bit unsure of when to make those judgement calls.

Comment: At the end of the day it _is_ a judgement call. This is all just my opinion. If your runnable cant handle an exception that is thrown by Scanner/File, then why have your runnable instantiate these types? Why not pass a valid Scanner into your Runnable. This would keep your try/catch in the main() where it sounds like that is where you want to handle this exception. What you end up doing with the exception is what matters. If you can recover from it, then throw it. If you are just going to log and fail silently, I say catch it within the Runnable.

Answer (score 0):

Initializing member variables in a constructor is generally good practice.  I think you are doing the right thing, and furthermore, I would move the initializations of `characters`, `words`, and `lines` into the constructor as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can silent the Exception, and abort file operations inside the thread. Whether silencing the exception is a good idea or not depends on what you're attempting to do.

```
try {
    inFile = new File(aFile);
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    System.out.println("file not found, aborting operation.");
    return;
}
```

However, I think there is nothing wrong with initializing the file in the constructor; it's a perfectly good practice if you want to fail early instead of waiting until later.

Answer (score -1):

If the problem is the checked exception then a common idiom is to convert it to a RuntimeException, something like this:

```
try {
 ...
} catch (IOException e) {
    throw new RuntimeException(e);
}
```

Basically you catch, convert and rethrow. RuntimeException is unchecked so the method signature does not need to declare it.

Comment: This is a bad idea IMO. You now have an unchecked exception which the compiler will not warn you about. What is the point of doing this? An exception is still going to be thrown, but now it wont be caught until runtime.